# In excel 2010 how to colour a cell based on values from another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, formatting, colors

I have a quite large table with several rows and for a easy visual trace I would like that a cell change color whenever a cell in another row has value. Let me try an example to be clearer:

Say that I have a table that has columns from `A` to `Z`. For an easy identification, I would like to have a formula, or formatting that whenever a cell on row `Z` is filled up (say `Z10`) the correspondent cell in column `A` (`A10`) would change its background colour to indicate that `Z10` had a value.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In conditional formatting you can add custom rules;

After clicking on the first cell in A that you want to format based on Z; in the main ribbon select Conditional Formatting > New Rule. In rule type select use formula to determine which cells to format. In your example in the box to determine where values are true put (no quotes)  "=Z1>0" then click on the format button and give it whatever style you want. This should sort out the one cell and the rest can be changed by the same method as applying a relative formula just drag the box or use Ctrl-D and it should apply the formula for each row.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It worked out exactly as I wanted.